# IOS Write to BLE Characteristic using Slider

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibaction

Really struggling with writing back to a BLE Peripheral. Please help...

I'm connected and have read the characteristics available and wish to write back from a IBAction Slider:

```
-(IBAction)SrControlIndex:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    switch (_SRControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            [self writeModeCharacteristic:Status_UUID data:[@"00" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSLog(@"First Sel");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Second Sel");
            break;
        default: 
            break; 
    }
}
```

And calls the following write:

```
-(void)writeModeCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)ModeCharacteristic data:(NSData*)data
    {
    [ModeCharacteristic.service.peripheral writeValue:data     forCharacteristic:ModeCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your issue exactly? What doesn't work? `Status_UUID` is a `CBCharacteristic` (its name suggests otherwise)? Please name your var starting with a lowercase.

Comment: Status_UUID is defined:
    #define Status_UUID @"346D0005-12A9-11CF-1279-81F2B7A91332"

Comment: So, that's a `NSString`, not a `CBCharacteristic`.

Comment: The code crashes when run with an error of:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString service]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10001c390'

Comment: That's normal. `writeModeCharacteristic:data:` is waiting for a `CBCharacteristic` as its first parameter and you're giving it a `NSString`.

Comment: Okay, I see where the issue is. I am sending NSString to CBCharacteristic. How do I convert the NSSrting into a CBCharacteristic

Comment: You don't. You have to keep a reference of the `CBCharacteristic` (when you discover it for example).

Comment: Sorry, really lost. I have discovered the characteristic already and set it to notify...what do I need to do?

Comment: When you discover the service and its characteristics you have to keep a reference to the appropriate discovered CBCharacteristic (in a property)

Comment: Thanks for help guys, but I really don't understand what you mean by keeping the discovered CBCharcateristic (in a property). If I have discovered a service then why can I not write to it?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCharacteristic statusCharacteristic;`
When you discovers it: `_statusCharacteristic = statusCharacteristicJustDiscovered;` Then you can reuse it in your method.

Comment: Great...I think its working (I now get an error stating that the data being sent has an invalid length)...next thing to sort out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Larme for the answer:

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCharacteristic statusCharacteristic; When you discovers it: _statusCharacteristic = statusCharacteristicJustDiscovered; Then you can reuse it in your method.

This worked great...

Answer (score 0):

An option is to keep the `CBPeripheral` object. After detecting services and characteristics you can run something like this:

```
for (CBService *service in self.peripheral.services) {
    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"YOUR-SERVICE-UUID"]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
            if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"YOUR-CHARACTERISTIC-UUID"]]) {
                [self.peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
            }
        }
    }
}
```